# Given a vector field, $\vec{F}$, and let $D$ be the domain of $\vec{F}$, how can we tell if $D$ is connected and/or simply connected?

Tags: connectedness, vector-fields, path-connected

For example: How can we tell that for $$\vec{F} = \bigg(\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2},\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2},z^2\bigg),$$ $D$ is **connected** but **not simply connected**? Where $D$ is the domain of $\vec{F}$.

Is this true? We can tell it is connected because $\vec{F}$ is conservative since we can test that the $(\nabla\times\vec{F})=0$. If this is true, is there an *easier* way to see that this is connected?

Comment: Connected but not simply connected because there is a singularity at the origin.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC how can you tell

Comment: Consider the point $(0,0,0)$; well this point is undefined because we have $0$ in the denominator of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: Additionally, there are singularities $\forall (0,0,z)$ points, i.e. all points along the $z$ axis.

Comment: $\nabla\times\vec F=0$ only tells you that the field is _irrotational_. Unless the domain is simply connected, you in fact cannot conclude from this that it’s conservative. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323418/265466 for a recent question that makes this same common error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, $D$ is connected but not simply connected because there are a series of points which are undefined in the domain.

Consider the origin, $(0,0,0)$; well this point is undefined because we have $0$ in the denominator of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Additionally, there are **singularities** $\forall (0,0,z)$ points, i.e. all points along the $z$-axis.

As you have asserted, we know that $\vec{F}$ is conservative because $\nabla\times\vec{F}=0$. These aforementioned singularities are **removable discontinuities.** If you put these ingredients together we have that $D$ is connected.